# Load the data by using sqlloader

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I am trying to load the data into the Oracle by using the sqlloader and want to give a specific date while loading.
Here is my control file.

```
LOAD DATA
--TRUNCATE
APPEND
INTO TABLE mcm.TEMP_2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
EMAIL_ADDRESS_  NULLIF EMAIL_ADDRESS_ = BLANKS,
EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_  NULLIF EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_ = BLANKS,
CREATED_TIME   '2022-08-05' 
)
```

The first two fields are populating from the file and CREATED_TIME  field want to populate with the
specific date. Here is the table I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE mcm.TEMP_2
  (EMAIL_ADDRESS_                      VARCHAR2(200) ,
    EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_            VARCHAR2(200) ,
    CREATED_TIME                        DATE     
)
```

But I am getting an error. Could you tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ah! You're getting an error! Only if we knew which one ... Also, sample data wouldn't do any harm (but quite a lot of good).

Meanwhile, I created my own test case, fixed your control file:

```
LOAD DATA
infile *
replace
INTO TABLE TEMP_2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
EMAIL_ADDRESS_             NULLIF EMAIL_ADDRESS_ = BLANKS,
EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_   NULLIF EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_ = BLANKS,
CREATED_TIME               "date '2022-08-05'" 
)

begindata
little@gmail.com|foot@yahoo.com|
|bigfoot@net.hr|2022-07-15
```

- disregard `infile` as I put sample data into control file
- `replace`d table contents
- fixed invalid column name (you made a typo)
- fixed date constant

and then ran SQL*Loader. Here's the result. (setting date format, just to know what it represents; you don't have to do that)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test10.ctl log=test10.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Aug 9 21:26:08 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEMP_2:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test10.log
for more information about the load.
```

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from temp_2;

EMAIL_ADDRESS_                 EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_       CREATED_TI
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
little@gmail.com               foot@yahoo.com                 05.08.2022
                               bigfoot@net.hr                 05.08.2022

SQL>
```